# return view($viewVariable) from a trait in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, routes, traits, laravel-8

I have a trait that is being called by several controllers in laravel 8.
Every controller gives the name of the return view allong with function on the trait.
If I do a `dd($viewVariable);` in the trait then I see the correct refrence to the view. But the trait refuses to return the view. It just gives me a blank screen. First I thought it was a problem with "no quotes", "singel quote" or dubbel quotes" but I tried every variation but without any succes.

I've tried setting the view the normal way but it even refused to render that. I've checked the other functions and variables with the `dd($var);` and everything is working correct till it's time to return the view.

### ChartTrait.php

```
public function setViewOptionsForChartGeneration($viewVariable)
    {

        // Check which role the user has in the application
        if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
            $recorderCollection = $this->getRecorderCollectionWhenAdmin();
            return view($viewVariable)->withRecorderCollection($recorderCollection);
        } elseif (Auth::user()->hasRole('employee|user')) {
            // Get all the valid timeslots that belongs to the authenticated user
            $userTimeslotCollection = $this->getUserTimeslot();
            // Get all the corresponding recorders from the valid timeslots that belongs to the authenticated user
            $recorderCollection = $this->onlyCollectRecordersBasedOnValidTimeslot($userTimeslotCollection);
            // return the view with all the possibility's the authenticated user has.
            return view($viewVariable)
                ->withRecorderCollection($recorderCollection->flatten())
                ->withUserTimeslotCollection($userTimeslotCollection);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There nothing wrong with the function in `ChartTrait.php`. The Problem was in the controllers. You need to **`return`** the function you call to render the view.

### Correct way of calling the trait

```
    public function index()
    {
        $view = "".'content.export.export'."";
        return $this->setViewOptionsForChartGeneration($view);
    }
```

### Wrong way of calling the trait

```
    public function index()
    {
        $view = "".'content.export.export'."";
        $this->setViewOptionsForChartGeneration($view);
    }
```